# Free or Relatively Less Pricey Quant Finance courses online

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, quantitative, quants

I am trying to figure out what all online Quant Finance courses are out there which are free or relatively less pricey?

- CQF is not less pricey
- Financial Engineering course on Coursera - Not so great unless you are a very basic learner
- Option Pricing course on EDX - I found it to be good.
- MIT Open Courseware videos - pretty good.
- Monte Carlo Methods in Finance - This was hosted on some MOOC platform in 2014. Pretty interesting for beginners

But most of the above ones except CQF is not a full fledged course which 1 can pursue. In today's world of MOOC's there are so many Data Science specializations out there but I don't see any on Quantitative Finance/Stochastic Calculus/Derivatives Modelling etc. courses out there.

Does anybody have any idea if any such courses are available or maybe about to be available?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This would make a very nice wiki thread

Comment: Yup, that's the idea, we all wanna learn, just need the correct resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just an update on my playlist, It has 33 videos now, roughly 3x more vids. I have included some more general economics and machine learning and programming vids, which have relevant applications in Q finance.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXFNpDcYOxM&list=PLqMiStH7exaXmQqV7y-tg68f2ZYZK3Yur

Answer (score 3):

I have a playlist on youtube I made and will continue updating:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXFNpDcYOxM&list=PLqMiStH7exaXmQqV7y-tg68f2ZYZK3Yur

Comment: This is really nice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Specialization course on Trading Algorithms. I haven't taken the course, but it seems good.

https://www.coursera.org/specializations/trading-strategy

Answer (score 2):

These certificates at UW are excellent and I highly recommend them.[UW CFRM certificate](https://depts.washington.edu/compfin/non-degree/certs/)

Comment: Not sure 500 and 800 USD/credit point qualifies as "less pricey".

Comment: Yes, the all inclusive price seems to be $13,000 :-(

Answer (score 0):

A free course to learn quant finance is:

[Python for Trading](https://quantra.quantinsti.com/course/python-trading-basic)

A very basic and free course on Python programming. It includes everything a beginner needs to know: data structures, expressions, functions and various libraries used in financial markets. This is a detailed and comprehensive course to build a strong foundation in Python.

The less pricey quant finance course is:

[Quantitative Strategies and Models](https://quantra.quantinsti.com/course/quantitative-trading-strategies-models)

This course for those starting their journey in quantitative trading. It includes Time Series Analysis, ARIMA GARCH models and implementation of Options and Derivatives. You will learn to think quantitatively and to create different trading strategies in Python.