# Algorithmic Trading

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading

I am a novice when it comes to algorithmic trading with strong interest in the subject matter. As I am looking around for online courses, I can only find one course called [Algorithmic Trading Strategies](https://www.experfy.com/training/courses/algorithmic-trading-strategies). The reviews look decent but it is hard to say if the course is for beginners like me or for someone who is more advanced. Any recommendations on how to get started?

Comment: Some related Q&A: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29957/free-or-relatively-less-pricey-quant-finance-courses-online https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34784/best-online-course-for-learning-quant-trading thre may be other better ones as well

Answer (score 1):

Look up any book from Ernest Chan.

such as this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Algorithmic-Trading-Winning-Strategies-Rationale-ebook/dp/B00CY5HC0U/ref=as_sl_pc_qf_sp_asin_til?tag=quantitativet-20&linkCode=w00&linkId=OKVO7DYTPENVN5Y7&creativeASIN=B00CY5HC0U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CY5HC0U)

This might not necessarily teach you how to code an algorithm from 0 to 1, but will give you the basic foundation in order to understand how an algorithm is stacked, how its built, what trading signals you are trying to generate and how to actually back-test and interpret the data.

You can also check his blog epchan.blogspot.com.

There are a wealth of communities as well such as quantopian.com that allow you to fiddle around with existing algorithms, and use their api to backtest and modify. It would be a good starting point, if you just want to go straight into the coding aspect. Some of the posted algorithms come with very detailed comments that can help