# Textbooks on algorithmic trading

Tags: algorithmic-trading, history, resource

What are good sources and textbooks covering the theory and models behind algorithmic trading and strategies?

Comment: As a starting point, you can look at this Q&A: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35014/algorithmic-trading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having traded algorithmically for a couple of decades and taught on the subject, I'm going to recommend four books: one practical, two theoretical (but important), and one that is light -- a "beach read" that still touches on many important topics.

The practical book is Barry Johnson's *Algorithmic Trading & DMA*. It is self-published and superb.

The theoretical books are very good at helping you look at algorithmic trading problems with a proper perspective. The two books I would suggest are Joel Hasbrouck's *Empirical Market Microstructure* and *Market Liquidity: Theory, Evidence, and Policy* by Thierry Foucault, Marco Pagano, and Alisa Röell.

Finally: the beach read. Go grab a copy of Lefèvre's *Reminiscences of a Stock Operator*. Many modern issues surrounding liquidity, order splitting, off-exchange trading and more are referenced in some way there. Prescient for a book written in 1923.

Comment: Welcome to Quant.SE!

Comment: Hartelijk dank! Good to be here!